# Java entity class with Boolean data type for Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a java entity which has a Boolean column:

```
private Boolean enabled;
void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
Boolean getEnabled() {
    return this.enabled;
}
```

when I am trying to set enable with true, i het the error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "enabled" is of type bit but expression is of type boolean
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

The Boolean type is supported in Postgresql, why do I get the error above?

Comment: Apparently the table was created with a `bit` column not a `boolean` column. You need to adjust your `CREATE TABLE` statement

Comment: I create the table from the entities (spring creates the tables automatically). The column is declared with Boolean.

Comment: Then apparently your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") doesn't know how to properly create a `boolean` column in Postgres

Comment: What should I do to create a boolean column?

Comment: `create table some_table (enabled boolean)`

Comment: The tables are generated based on the entity pojo classes,

Comment: The inability to control the DDL is one of the reasons I don't use obfuscation layers to create my database model. Use SQL scripts stored in your source control to manage your schema and schema migrations.